# Google Sheets - make a static link to a cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, libreoffice-calc

I want to "hyperlink" from SheetA(cell:A1) to SheetB(cell:A1). To accomplish that, on SheetA:A1 I do Ctrl-K and link to SheetB!A1. Fine. If I add a row in SheetB above 1st row, the reference is broken in SheetA(cell:A1). How do I make a statically make an hyperlink to SheetB(cell:A1) in such a way that even if rows are added the hyperlink from SheetA(cell:A1) points to addend cell in SheetB?

Please help with the solution for Google Sheets and LibreOffice Calc.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `=SheetB!A1` instead of Ctl+K.

Comment: @Variatus I want to link the destination as "hyperlink".

Comment: Are you willing to use Apps Script?

Comment: @Aerials I have two versions of same data. So, will same script work in Google Sheets and LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: You could connect Apps Script to external APIs too. But how are you creating this LibreOffice document?

Comment: @Aerials Source is LibreOffice. New sheets are manually copied to Google Sheets.

Comment: Where/when does the hyperlink come into play?

Comment: after doing `on SheetA:A1 I do Ctrl-K and link to SheetB!A1`, how does the (inline equation, `hyperlink()`) link look like?

Comment: @p._phidot_ It's not an equation/formula. Before doing Ctrl-K, text on the source cell must be selected. Say there is a text "hello" on SheetA:A1 cell, after doing Ctrl-K on it and linking to SheetB!A1, "hello" becomes a link and when clicked upon, the control goes to SheetB!A1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't achieve what you want using formulas or shortcuts (or any simple script for that matter), as the current behavior transposes the hyperlink when there are new rows added.